# Active Admin Filters no viewing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So I'm in Active Admin and in the following model a `Degree belongs to a user` and a `User has many degrees`

For a `User` we have a `site_id` that identifies where the User works in a `Site` table

So in my filter in Active Admin's degree model, I can't seem to pull a list of sites that someone can filter from in the Active Admin UI.

Here are my filters so far:
`major`
`institution`
`completion_date`

These are straight from the `Degree` tables

`:user_active` comes from Users table with a boolean attribute for an an `Active`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Degree do

  belongs_to :user, :optional => true

  menu :parent => 'Users'

  config.sort_order = 'users.last_name_asc'

  filter :user_active, :as => :select
  **filter :site_id, collection: -> { User.all }, label: 'sites'**
  filter :degree_type
  filter :major
  filter :institution
  filter :completion_date
```

I've tried this as well

```
  filter :site_id, :as => :select, collection: -> { User.all }, label: 'sites'
```

and no error message

I've also tried something like this with no error message, but nothing in the UI comes through again

```
filter :site, label: "Site", :as => :select, :collection => User.site_id
```

I've tried this and get the following errors:

```
  filter :site_id, label: "Site", :as => :select, :collection => User.all

undefined method `site_id_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: Degree, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Any help here?

**Update**

I did some work-around and this is what I end-ed up with

```
filter :user_site_id, label: "site", :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map{|u| u.site}.map{|s| s.city if s.present? }.uniq.compact
```

The collection says

1. Iterated through all the users and call u.site (because a site_id
   belongs to a User so there's a Site table that'll take each instance
   of a user)
2. Since we're now at each Site object, map each of those
   values and retrieve the city name for each Site object if it's
   present...
3. I want to only filter the uniq values and .compact is
   getting rid of the nil values in the array

I think there's a better solution because I'm going through so many iterations?  Anyone have any other ideas?  I'm going to make this an instance method on the Users model after the refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
 filter :site_id, as: :select, collection: -> { User.pluck(:site_id) }, label: 'Sites'
```

Comment: Just tried it:  ```undefined method `site_id_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: Degree, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search```

Comment: I did some work around that's like this ```filter :user_site_id, label: "site", :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map{|u| u.site}.map{|s| s.city if s.present? }.uniq.compact```

Comment: Actually @AndreyDeineko, yours works, if you do a `filter :user_site_id` instead of a `filter :site_id`    I'm not quite understanding how ransack is working, but after that I though I could call .city since the Site table has a city attribute.

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this is a good solution.